# Can there be a Regex : "First two character should not be same in a string"

Tags: regex

Can there be such regex?

First two characters should not be same in a string.

Comment: `^(.)(?!\1)` for engines supporting look-ahead

Comment: @nhahtdh: Post it. Most languages support look-aheads.

Comment: @nhahtdh: you should post an answer with that.

Comment: Using in Javascript.(later in ruby I may need it)

Comment: Do you really have to use a regex? `str[0] !== str[1]` would be much simpler.

Comment: @Juhana Yeah. That I was doing, but was forced to use regex!

Comment: @Thealon No sir. Actually I'm new to regex (even javascript, jquery and all that), I'm more a Java Dev. But you know, client pressure sometimes. Haven't use characters matching within same string. (Didn't even saw when I was studying regex, my mistake). Though after such an early response, I'm repeanting that I must have searched a bit before. Thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For engines supporting look-ahead (which is the case in most languages), you can use this:

```
^(.)(?!\1)
```

It captures the first character and checks that the next character is not the same character, with negative look-ahead and backreference `\1`.

Though as [Juhana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502381/juhana) stated in the comment, you should consider using normal string operations to check, unless regex is the only option available.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
(?:^|\s)(\w)\1
```

for matching repeated characters at the start of a string

Comment: I needed to get strings with Non-repeating char. But it is also worthy of use somewhere else.